# How to create old-fashion scientific diagrams using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I would like to reproduce following scientific diagram in a 1996 paper. 
[image: An old-fashion scientific diagram]

My questions:

(a) How did the author create such a figure? What software did he possibly used?

(b) Is it possible to do it using `TikZ`? If so, what is the general routine?

I appreciate your helps.

Comment: (a) Judging from the arrow tips and other imperfections, it looks like a hand-drawn sketch from the pre-PC era. (b) `\begin{tikzpicture}` *drawing commands* `\end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: For 3d, start at the back and work foreward.

Comment: Also note that tikz does allow you to specify 3-dimensional coordinates `(x,y,z)`, which it projects onto the page. The default perspective is basically the one in your diagram, but it can also be changed.

Comment: `tikz-3dplot` can help with the calculations @Emma mentions. However, Ti*k*Z is not the most obvious choice for 3D as it can only ever fake it in 2D.

Comment: Off-topic: Why is that old-fashioned?

Comment: @Johannes_B You can tell from the style. As AlexG said it looks like a hand-drawn sketch. Figures in 21 centuries are more fancy.

Comment: So you want to recreate the *hand-drawn sketch*? Just use the picture and include it.

Comment: @Johannes_B Not exactly. It _is_ hand-drawn, but I would rather create a similar diagram using tools like `TikZ`.

Comment: This drawing is a technical drawing drawn in Chinese ink as we learned before the massive use of computers. But, the image that you show is certainly the result of a photocopy of photocopy, which systematically damages the layout and makes it approachable: the photocopiers do not reproduce perfectly: there are always traces slightly damaged. All you need to do to convince yourself is to make photocopies of photocopies and you will get the same effect. I'm sure the original is much cleaner than that.

Comment: @AndréC This is a really good point. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At least it works …

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,shapes.arrows,positioning}
\tikzset{arrownode/.style={
        transform shape nonlinear=true,
        shape=double arrow,
        shape border rotate=180,
        draw
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,every node/.style={font=\footnotesize}]
        \draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) node[above] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.7) node[right] {$y$};
            \draw[xshift=.5cm,yshift=1cm] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
                \draw[xshift=.5cm,yshift=1cm,white] (0,0) -- (0,2);
                \draw[xshift=.5cm,yshift=1cm,white] (0,0) -- (2,0);
                    \draw[xshift=.5cm,yshift=1cm,thick] (0,2) -- (2,2);
            \draw[fill=white,xshift=.5cm,yshift=1cm] (0,2) -- ([xshift=-.05cm,yshift=-.1cm]0,2) -- (1,1.8) -- ([xshift=-.05cm,yshift=-.1cm]2,2) -- (2,2);
            \draw[xshift=.5cm,yshift=1cm] ([xshift=-.05cm,yshift=-.1cm]2,2) -- ([xshift=-.15cm]2,1) -- ([xshift=-.05cm,yshift=-.1cm]2,0) -- (2,0);
            \draw[fill=white,xshift=.5cm,yshift=1cm] ([xshift=-.05cm,yshift=-.1cm]2,0) -- ([yshift=-.2cm]1,0) -- (0,0) -- ([xshift=-.2cm]0,1) -- ([xshift=-.05cm,yshift=-.1cm]0,2);
            \draw[fill=white,xshift=.5cm,yshift=1cm] ([xshift=-.2cm]0,1) -- ([yshift=-.2cm].9,1) -- ([xshift=-.15cm]2,1);
            \draw[xshift=.5cm,yshift=1cm] (1,1.8) -- ([yshift=-.2cm].9,1) -- ([yshift=-.2cm]1,0);
            \draw[xshift=.5cm,yshift=1cm,fill=white] ([xshift=-.05cm,yshift=-.1cm]2,0) -- ([xshift=-.15cm]2,1) -- ([yshift=-.2cm].9,1) -- (1,-.2) -- cycle;
            \draw[xshift=.5cm,yshift=1cm,fill=white] ([xshift=-.05cm,yshift=-.1cm]0,2) -- ([xshift=-.2cm]0,1) -- ([yshift=-.2cm].9,1) -- (1,1.8) -- cycle;
                \draw[xshift=.5cm,yshift=1.2cm] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(.5,1)(.4,.5)(.8,.2)(1.2,.3)(1.5,.5)(1.4,.8)(1.2,1)(1,1.1)};
            \draw[xshift=.5cm,yshift=1cm,fill=white] (2,2) -- ([xshift=-.05cm,yshift=-.1cm]2,2) -- ([xshift=-.15cm]2,1) -- ([xshift=-.05cm,yshift=-.1cm]2,0) -- (2,0) -- cycle;
        \draw (-1.4,0) -- ([xshift=.5cm,yshift=1.2cm].5,1);
        \draw (0,-1) -- ([xshift=.5cm,yshift=1.2cm]1.2,.3);
        \draw[shorten <=-.6cm,shorten >=.23cm,dash pattern=on 5pt off 1pt on .5 off 1pt] (0,0) -- ([xshift=.55cm,yshift=1cm]1,1);
        \begin{scope}[xshift=1.9cm,yshift=2.5cm]
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
                \draw[fill=white,radius=1.3cm] (.2,.2) circle;
                \draw[fill=white,radius=1.3cm] (0,0) circle;
                \coordinate (a) at (1.12,1.12);
            \end{pgfonlayer}
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[shift={(3.5,3.5)}]
            \foreach \x in {1,2}
            \foreach \y in {1,2}
            {
                \draw[radius=.4cm] (\x,\y) circle;
            }
                \coordinate (b) at (.68,2.25);
                \coordinate (c) at ([xshift=1cm].68,2.25);
                \coordinate (d) at ([yshift=-1cm].68,2.25);
                \coordinate (e) at ([xshift=1cm,yshift=-1cm].68,2.25);
                    \coordinate (c1) at (1.35,1.8);
                    \coordinate (c2) at ([xshift=1cm]1.35,1.8);
                    \coordinate (c3) at ([yshift=-1cm]1.35,1.8);
                    \coordinate (c4) at ([xshift=1cm,yshift=-1cm]1.35,1.8);
            \draw (.5,.5) rectangle (2.5,2.5);
                \draw[dashed] (a) -- (1.5,1.5) node[pos=.34,above] {$b$};
                \draw[dashed] (c) -- ([xshift=-1.5cm,yshift=.25cm]a) -- (b);
                \draw[dashed] (d) -- ([xshift=-1.45cm,yshift=.29cm]a) -- (e);
                    \draw[dashed] (c1) -- ([xshift=.25cm,yshift=-1.5cm]a) -- (c2);
                    \draw[dashed] (c3) -- ([xshift=.25cm,yshift=-1.5cm]a) -- (c4);
            \node at (2.7,.3)  {\tiny Detector};
            \node at (0,2.7) {\tiny Pupils (abcd)};
                \draw[->] (1.5,2) -- (3,2) node[above] {$s$};
                \draw[->] (2,1.5) -- (2,3) node[right] {$t$};
                    \node at (.2,2.2) {$a$};
                    \node at (2.7,1) {$d$};
                    \node at (2.7,1.7) {$c$};
        \end{scope}
        \node[text width=1.7cm,left] at (-.5,1.3) {\tiny Large $F$/focus of the telescope};
        \node[text width=3cm] (n) at (4.5,0) {\tiny Blurred image of a reference source};
            \draw[->] (n) to[in=-20,out=170] ([xshift=.5cm,yshift=1.2cm]1.2,.3);
        \node at (4,1.5) {Lens Relay};
        \node[yscale=.5,arrownode] (node) at (-.5,3.3) {\phantom{\hspace{.7cm}}};
        \node[rotate=90,yscale=.5,arrownode,above=1 of node,yshift=-.1cm] (nnode) {\phantom{\hspace{.7cm}}};
        \node[above of=nnode] {\tiny Oscillating Pyramidal Prism};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Awesome! How did you `\draw` each command? I would imagine a LOT manual efforts. Any automatic ways to do it?

Comment: Nice! Did you use an external program to draw the picture and then copy the code into `LaTeX`?

Comment: @manooooh: No, I just literally draw this "by hand and eye" … (I think you asked me that 'cause of all the manual shifting … xD)

Comment: @WDC: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @current_user Your previous reply has answered my question. So you did it all manually. This is really, really cool. Thank you.

Comment: For me excellent work. +1

Answer (score 5):

For my opinion, the figure is very complex to built with TikZ. 
It takes a lot of time; but if you want be quickly to realize your picture without to know TikZ, you can use, in particular,

- IPE, http://ipe.otfried.org/;
- XFig or WinFig, http://winfig.com/;
- *InkScape*, https://pav.iki.fi/software/textext/. With *InkScape* can you export your picture in .tex.
- GraTeX a Visual graph creator for LaTeX (PGF & TikZ) for designed graph with a single-click operation, [GraTeX](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gratex/).